# Multiple output because of foreach and for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I am reading a bunch of excel files and inserting their data inside database. The queries are all working correctly. Only problem is if an author is present in first excel file its entry is also showing in other excel file also. This is my code.

```
$array = array(
1=>"abc",
2=>"def",
3=>"age");

foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
    $file = $array[$key].'.xls';
    $data->read($file);
    $ID = $key;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
        $a = addslashes($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1]);
        if($a == "Ali")
        {
             echo $a."=>".$ID." ".$i."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

**The desired output is**

```
abc.xls
Ali=>1 282
def.xls
age.xls
```

and the output coming is

```
abc.xls
Ali=>1 282
def.xls
Ali=>2 282
age.xls
Ali=>3 282
```

Can anybody tell me where is mistake in this code. Any help will be appreciate..

**NOTE** The number of rows present in excel sheet are 100.

Comment: The code just work as expected, doesn't it?

Comment: @xdazz yes, but i don't know why it is not working as expected.

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong if we don't have the input to the code. Looks like `$data->sheets[0]['numRows']` had 3 elements but you only want to use one of them.

Comment: @sachleen what input you want ? tell me i will add it in question.

Comment: What is the expected output of  $a = addslashes($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1]);
when $a is not "Ali"? Will it have any value? or will there be such a column in the excel file in this case?

Comment: Add `unset($a)` just before the for loop closing brace. It'll unset the value  of $a before the next loop iteration.

Comment: @saji89: looks like the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't included this lines inside `foreach` loop , because of that $data is always taking 1st excel file. Not taking further files. This lines are included before foreach loop.

The lines are

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('utf-8');
```

Now code becomes

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $data->setOutputEncoding('utf-8');
    $file = $array[$key].'.xls';
    $data->read($file);
    $ID = $key;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
       $a = addslashes($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1]);
       if($a == "Ali")
       {
         echo $a."=>".$ID." ".$i."<br>";
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like the issue is whatever is column 1 of that specific row is always `"Ali"`. Thats a guess though because your output is as expected with the exception of the two extra `Ali=>1 282`. It would help if you could give us the first few rows just to understand. Otherwise this really seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to unset(destroy) the current value of `$a` at end of each loop iteration.
The required change is as follows:
Change the following:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
    $a = addslashes($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1]);
    if($a == "Ali")
    {
      echo $a."=>".$ID." ".$i."<br>";
    }
}
```

to this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
    $a = addslashes($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1]);
    if($a == "Ali")
    {
      echo $a."=>".$ID." ".$i."<br>";
    }
    unset($a);
}
```